# unknown issue with search geometry in Planet API

Tags: python, api, planet

I'm trying to download some images from the Planet API using a MultiLineString geometry. I did a test with a simple MultiLine and it worked. Now I tried with a more complex one (and not that much):

[image: roads]

and I get this error:

> {
>    "field": {},
>    "general": [
>     {
>      "message": "unknown issue with search geometry"
>     }
>    ]
>   }

I have seen a few people working at Planet here, so maybe someone knows about the issue?

**Edit**

Reducing the number of lines, and simplifying geometries, I got this error:

> "message": "Sorry, your request timed out. The usual cause of this is the default AOI on your account may encompass too large of a geographic area or, has too many vertices. We recommend you pass in a smaller and simpler AOI to your query. Please visit https://www.planet.com/docs/reference/data-api/search-api/ for instructions on how to supply an AOI to your query via the GeometryFilter."

So, does anyone know the maximum area or number of vertices that are allowed?

Comment: Could you prove the geometry in question?